# How to check multiply results in unit testing Swift?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I am doing unit testing for a program. I have a func:

```
 static func make(for lesson: TrainingProgram.Lesson,
                     in program: TrainingProgram,
                     results: [String: TrickResults]) -> [TrickContent]
```

In unit testing I written this:

```
let session = TrainingSessionFactory.make(for: lesson,
                                                  in: program,
                                                  results: [trainedTrickId: result])
```

And I want to test in results: `[trainedTrickId: result]` and like `[trainedTrickId: resultsTwo]`, `[trainedTrickId: resultsThree]`

But want to shorten my test code so don't want to make another session for different results. How do I do that?

result, resultsTwo, resultsThree have different values:

```
let result = TrickResults(id: trainedTrickId,
                                  knowledge: 4,
                                  points: 0,
                                  lastTrainedOn: 0,
                                  lastRatedOn: 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already solved. But in any case someone would look for answer, here it is:

```
let session = TrainingSessionFactory.make(for: lesson,
                                                  in: program,
                                                  results: [trainedTrickId: result,
                                                            trainedTrickId: results2,
                                                            trainedTrickId: results3])
```